# How to make a rest call to SharePoint 2013 from node.js?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, nodejs

In my node.js app, I want to make a rest call to sharepoint 2013. This is the node.js code

```
function downloadData(res, key, success, fail) {    
    var opts = url.parse(key);


    opts.method = 'GET';
    opts.headers = {"Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose","X-RequestDigest":"0x146E2BDC9A21FDA62E793A0FC9793A530A5C6688BE194FB051703C8529B01A16607931C77D26EE61FA360AD04526F476A052FAC9B3C9277A5463AC20A27C3543,07 Mar 2016 15:37:18 -0000"};
    opts.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;odata=nometadata';

    var req = http.request(opts, function(response) {
        var str = '';

        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
        response.on('end', function () {
            success(res, str, key);
        });
    })

    //req.write(data);
    req.end();
}
```

I got the digest value from the client side, I did an alert statement, and copied it. I tried it on a sample url, which does work if I paste on the browser. When I run this, I get 401 unauthorized.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

---

Here is what I have so far:

js

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://myserver:3000/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('NewsNews')/items",
                type: "GET", 
                headers: {
                            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                        },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });
```

node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

var cacheObj = {};

app.get('/_api/web*', function (req, res) {
    var key = req.originalUrl;
    req.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;odata=nometadata";
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    processIncomingCall(key, res, req.headers);
});

function processIncomingCall(key, res, headers) {
    var val = cacheObj[key];

    if (val) {
        console.log(val);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(val));
    } else {
        downloadData(res, key, headers, function(res, data, key) {
            cacheObj[key] = data;
            setTimeout(function(key) {
                delete cacheObj[key];
            }, 1000 * 5, key);
            res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, function() {

        });
    }
}

function downloadData(res, key, headers, success, fail) {
    var opts = url.parse(key);
    opts.method = 'GET';
    opts.headers = headers;

    var req = http.request(opts, function(response) {
        var str = '';

        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
        response.on('end', function () {
            success(res, str, key);
        });
    })

    //req.write(data);
    req.end();
}

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Started at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/csom-node - well it's not REST, it's JSOM, but it works, and authentication stuff is working.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do REST calls, not jsom.

Comment: I have never looked at the details.. Vadim has something server to SP with REST: https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

Comment: @omega are you SharePoint Online or on-premise?

Comment: Also please take a look at this project - [sp-rest-proxy](https://github.com/koltyakov/sp-rest-proxy)

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [`sp-request`](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/sp-request)
With `sp-request` you can easily send REST queires:

```
var spr = require('sp-request').create(credentialOptions);
spr.get('http://sp2013dev/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'TestList\')')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log('List Id: ' + response.body.d.Id);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log('Ohhh, something went wrong...');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which must be in place:

**1. The Authorization Header:**
EndpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization",   "Bearer " + accessToken);

**2. Request Digest,** (as you already know): It would be best if you get a new one every time. You do this by calling siteulrl/_api/contextinfo and parsing the token from the xml file.

As Andrey statet, look a the JSOM Package it uses the same authentication mechanisms as the REST interface. So the authentication code should be around there. Using Fiddler, you can also take a closer look at your http-Headers.

Comment: What I am doing is making a node.js middle man on my farm, so when a user makes a rest call from the client side, I change it to go to my node.js process, then make the actual rest call from there. So is it possible I can forward the authentication from the client to the node.js process when node.js makes the rest call? So the node.js rest calls runs as the user from the client side.

Comment: Actually that is possible. It is called delegation. It is usually done with kerberos. But is quite a big topic and maybe it is okay for your purposes to work perform your requests with a system account.

Comment: Actually I need it to use the current user rather than a system account, as REST calls gets security trimmed, so I need user accounts.

Comment: I tried, taking the digest information that the client sends to the server, get that in node, then set that header in the http request in node, but I still get 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Yes that is because you are still missing the authorization header, that is not the same as the request digest. You have basically 2 options: Configure kerberos if you are on premise or use oauth if you are using sharepoint online. The problem you are facing right now is called "double hop problem", you will find a lot of information on the web about that 

Comment: @HarryBerry it is possible via kerberos when we are talking about IIS, **omega** wants to do that via nodejs which is completely different story. kerberos doesn't help in this situation

Comment: wow just noticed this thread is in March :))) Sorry for mentions :)